# NGINX how to check if last part of an URI consist of 32 symbols and also fits into regexp [a-z0-9] using map {}?

Tags: nginx, extract

There is an URI **/part1/part2/partX/md5**

How to extract using map {} last part of URI and check its length ( eq 32 symbols ) and then check does it fits into regexp [0-9a-z].

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Adding quotes around the regex should allow `{32}` to be used.

Not a very satisfying approach, but it works:

```
map $request_uri $count32 {
    ~/(?<last>[0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z])$ $last;
}
```

```
if ($count32) {
   return 200 "Last component has 32 characters: $count32
";
}
```

Comment: While waiting for someone to answer, I was researching and found this solution `map $request_uri $count32 {
"~/(?<last>[a-z0-9]{32})$" $last;
}`

Comment: That was the first thing I tried with nginx/1.11.5 but it didn't work. Maybe that functionality has been added in newer versions.

Comment: I upgraded to nginx/1.23.3 and `{32}` works for me now, but I may not have tried with quotes. It may have worked in version 1.11.5.